# Animating scrolltop event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I'm trying to animate a `scrolltop` action, when I click on the back to top button however, it snaps back to top without animation, could this be a CSS parameter error?

This is the script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 990) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn(600)
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut(300)
        }
    });
    $('.scrollup').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="toparrow">
    <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS element:

```css
#toparrow {

}
.scrollup {
    width:72px;
    height:45px;
    top:240px;
    left:927px;
    position:absolute;
    background: url('../img/generic/toparrow.png') bottom;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

and the website : http://www.citrontech.com/services

Comment: sorry:  <div id="toparrow"><a  href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a></div>

Comment: you need preventDefault() if you use anchor tag, or you can use '<span>'. Seems you got the answer.

Comment: <span> to replace what?

Comment: like this, <span class="scrollup">Scroll</span>?

Comment: ok i answered while you answered :), now the button is unclickable, but im sure i can find out why.

Comment: but animating is done or not? just wanna know

Comment: got to figure out why I cannot click on the button to test that  out :/

Comment: its still clickable, but the cursor style is not an arrow, right?

Comment: well no its just an simple image now, i suppose since there nothing telling it its a button.

Comment: LotusH got it, but thanks for your help and your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the button is an anchor with the `href="#"` which means go to the top section. You could use `preventDefault` to change this browser behavior.

```
 $('.scrollup').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
     return false;
 });
```

More about `event.preventDefault`: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Still the same problem, however im gonna read up on preventDefault, cheers

Comment: weird, trying on all browsers and doesnt animate.

Comment: Wrap this function in document.ready. i.e. `$(function(){$('.scrollup').click(...)})`.

Comment: My, Hero. Thanks you all for your help. (I cant vote up this question cause im too newb, someone else does :)

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 990) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn(600)
    }
    else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut(300)
    }
});
 $('.scrollup').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
     return false;
  
 });
});